# How can I set the fill color of a built-in Bing Maps AJAX7 SDK pushpin?

Tags: colors, icons, bing-maps, pushpin

I am using the Bing Maps AJAX7 SDK and need to use pushpins of several different colors to represent several different statuses (red, green, gray, and white). I've studied the documentation looking for a way to use the default icon and simply set the fill color, but to no avail.

I am aware that some clever things can be done using HTML and CSS, but I'm hoping to avoid all of that for now.

Is it possible to use the Bing Maps default pushpin but change the fill color?

Actually the icon my customer wants to use is #46 at this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701719.aspx 
My customer chose that icon thinking that I could simply select it using my Pushpin object or PushpinOptions object, but I am not sure that's the case.

If using a built-in icon and setting a different fill color is not possible, then can someone tell me where I can get a set of Bing Maps icons or very similar ones that are free for commercial use?

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX control only has one pushpin. To change the pushpin you need different images to replace as the icon. For example: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins2

Alternatively you can create canvas pushpins: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/html5-canvas-pushpins-in-javascript/

The custom pushpins you see in the documentation (i.e. #46) is for the REST imagery service only. The reason for this is that for security reasons users can not specify image URL's for the imagery service so custom pushpin icons can only be selected from a set of predefined pushpins. These are not made available outside of this service as this is very limiting compared to being able to create your own custom pushpins.